# Selection of columns for the table in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to add a new category at the beginning which will select the columns for the table. I can not combine variables with other elements in an application. Could someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? As you can see on the graphics program does not work well.
[image]

## My code:

```
 library(shiny)

data <- data.frame(
  Category1 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 15),
  Info = paste("Text info", 1:45),
  Category2 = sample(letters[15:20], 45, replace = T),
  Size = sample(1:100, 45),
  MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff", 1:45)
)
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      "show_vars",
                      "Columns to show:",
                      choices = colnames(data),
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2")
                    ),
                    uiOutput("category1"),
                    uiOutput("category2"),
                    uiOutput("sizeslider")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
                ))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$table)
    if (input$table == "All") {
      return(data)
    }
    data[, names(data) %in% input$show_vars]
  })
  
  output$category1 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput('cat1',
                   'Choose Cat 1',
                   choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                     unique(data$Category1)
                   ))),
                   selected = "All")
  })
  
  df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
    if (input$cat1 == "All") {
      df_subset <- data
    }
    else{
      df_subset <- data[data$Category1 == input$cat1, ]
    }
  })
  
  df_subset1 <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
      df_subset()
    } else {
      df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2, ]
    }
  })
  
  output$category2 <- renderUI({
    selectizeInput(
      'cat2',
      'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
      choices = sort(as.character(unique(
        df_subset()$Category2
      ))),
      multiple = TRUE,
      options = NULL
    )
  })
  
  output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
    sliderInput(
      "size",
      label = "Size Range",
      min = min(df_subset1()$Size),
      max = max(df_subset1()$Size),
      value = c(min(df_subset1()$Size), max(df_subset1()$Size))
    )
  })
  
  df_subset2 <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$size)) {
      df_subset1()
    } else {
      df_subset1()[df_subset1()$Size >= input$size[1] &
                     df_subset1()$Size <= input$size[2], ]
    }
  })
  
  output$table <- renderTable({
    df_subset2()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Can you explain more, could not understand what output you are expecting.

Comment: Where does `input$table` get created?  It seems the subset column function never gets triggered because that input was never created. Also, the data from that never gets called either.

Comment: @user5249203 As you can see in the graphic above, I chose three columns and all are shown.

Comment: @RyanMorton you could write to me where to create input$table?

Comment: @RyanMorton or show an example where is this clearly explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few problems with your code

1. You stored that reactive value of the columns selection in `data2()`, and displaying table `df_subset2()`. As with your code, the columns change when you add columns and select `Cat1` dropdown, since its values are dependent on the `data.react`.
2. Avoid using generic names like `data` to store data. Sometimes it interfere with R base names
3. You need to use `ObserveEvent` and `eventReactive`, when you expect the change on UI to reflect

Below is what I fixed, you can change accordingly.

1. Added a submit button
2. Wrapped the input selections code into an `ObserveEvent`
   By this, your data is displayed only when you click the submit button.

Here is the code.

---

```
library(shiny)

data.input <- data.frame(
  Category1 = rep(letters[1:3], each = 15),
  Info = paste("Text info", 1:45),
  Category2 = sample(letters[15:20], 45, replace = T),
  Size = sample(1:100, 45),
  MoreStuff = paste("More Stuff", 1:45)
)
```

---

**ui.r**

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Test Explorer"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    selectizeInput(
                      "show_vars",
                      "Columns to show:",
                      choices = colnames(data.input),
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      selected = c("Category1", "Info", "Category2")
                    ),
                    actionButton("button", "An action button"),
                    uiOutput("category1"),
                    uiOutput("category2"),
                    uiOutput("sizeslider")
                  ),
                  mainPanel(tableOutput("table"))
                ))
```

---

**server.r**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data.react <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    data.input[, input$show_vars]
  })
  observeEvent(input$button, {
    output$category1 <- renderUI({
      data.sel <- data.react()
      selectizeInput('cat1',
                     'Choose Cat 1',
                     choices = c("All", sort(as.character(
                       unique(data.sel$Category1)
                     ))),
                     selected = "All")
    })

    df_subset <- eventReactive(input$cat1, {
      data.sel <- data.react()
      if (input$cat1 == "All") {
        data.sel
      }
      else{
        data.sel[data.sel$Category1 == input$cat1,]
      }
    })

    output$category2 <- renderUI({
      selectizeInput(
        'cat2',
        'Choose Cat 2 (optional):',
        choices = sort(as.character(unique(
          df_subset()$Category2
        ))),
        multiple = TRUE,
        options = NULL
      )
    })

    df_subset1 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$cat2)) {
        df_subset()
      } else {
        df_subset()[df_subset()$Category2 %in% input$cat2,]
      }
    })

    output$sizeslider <- renderUI({
      sliderInput(
        "size",
        label = "Size Range",
        min = min(data.input$Size),
        max = max(data.input$Size),
        value = c(min(data.input$Size), max(data.input$Size))
      )
    })

    df_subset2 <- reactive({
      if (is.null(input$size)) {
        df_subset1()
      } else {
        df_subset1()[data.input$Size >= input$size[1] &
                       data.input$Size <= input$size[2],]
      }
    })
    output$table <- renderTable({
      df_subset2()

    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But as I swapped the server and added actionButton, I get an error: `Warning: Error in eventReactiveHandler: object 'data.input' not found` :(

Comment: The error pops up when you click on the button `An action button`

Comment: I noticed that in your version version of the app the sizeslider shows bad fields in the table.